# map multiple values without hardcoding

Tags: python, regex

I am reading each row source data below using for loop then i am fetching values in array and using this i need to convert it to required format, i am able to convert when row array has only two value but more than that as in Row 3

Source data

```
 Row 1:
    [(array['X'] <@ type_list AND (array['X6'] <@ value_list OR array['A6.5'] <@ value_list OR array['YZ'] <@ value_list)]
 Row 2:
    [(array['Z'] <@ type_list AND array['30'] <@ value_list)]
 Row 3:
[(array['KZA'] <@ type_list AND (array['AM'] <@ value_list OR array['UA'] <@ value_list OR array['RC'] <@ value_list OR array['WEQZ4.5'] <@ value_list)]
```

Code:

```
import re
regex = r"array\['(?P<array>.*?)\']"
for val in data1:
    data=val
    arrVal2 = re.findall(regex, str(data))
    cntInnr2=len(arrVal2)
    rt=arrVal2[0]
    for cont in range(cntInnr2):
        if rt != arrVal2[cont]:
            val1=arrVal2[cont]
            updVal=("(type_value LIKE ANY ('%%%s=%s;%%'))" % (rt, val1))
            #f=f.replace(data, updVal)
```

After conversion, rows should look like below:

```
  Row 1:
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%X=X6;%','%X=A6.5;%','%X=YZ;%'))

  Row 2:
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%Z=30;%'))

  Row 3:
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%KZA=AM;%','%KZA=UA%','%KZA=RC;%','%KZA=WEQZ4.5;%'))
```

I am able to handle `Row 2` through above code but unable to handle if there are more value such as in `Row 1` and `Row 3`

Comment: In the for loop just build the string `"'%X=X6;%','%X=A6.5%','%X=YZ;%'"` and then append `(type_value LIKE ANY (` later, that should work..

Comment: There are multiple rows with different values, I need to handle them all

Comment: Why is `;` only after `X6`? Shouldn't the expected result be `(type_value LIKE ANY ('%X=X6;%','%X=A6.5;%','%X=YZ;%'))`?

Comment: That's right, let me correct it

Comment: Yes.. the approach I suggested is generic... It will work for multiple rows with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the value inside `array['...']` and then use it as a key later, then collect the values between `array['` and `']` that are after `<@ type_list` (to be used as values later), and then build the result:

```
import re
strs=["[(array['X'] <@ type_list AND (array['X6'] <@ value_list OR array['A6.5'] <@ value_list OR array['YZ'] <@ value_list)]", "[(array['Z'] <@ type_list AND array['30'] <@ value_list)]", "[(array['KZA'] <@ type_list AND (array['AM'] <@ value_list OR array['UA'] <@ value_list OR array['RC'] <@ value_list OR array['WEQZ4.5'] <@ value_list)]"]
r = re.compile(r"array\['(.*?)']")    # Compile the regex
for s in strs:
    m = r.search(s)                   # Get the key value
    if m:                             # If we found it
        array_vals = r.findall(s, s.index("<@ type_list")) # Get the values
        if len(array_vals) > 0:       # If there is at least 1 value, build the result
            print("(type_value LIKE ANY ({}))".format(",".join(["'%{}={};%'".format(m.group(1), x) for x in array_vals])))
```

Output:

```
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%X=X6;%','%X=A6.5;%','%X=YZ;%'))
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%Z=30;%'))
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%KZA=AM;%','%KZA=UA;%','%KZA=RC;%','%KZA=WEQZ4.5;%'))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jURSSs).

You will probably want to add a check if `array_vals` contain at least one value,  e.g. using `if len(array_vals) > 0:`.

Comment: Aren't we hard coding `%X`  which is there only in `Row 1` and not in others ? `print("(type_value LIKE ANY ('%X={};%'))"`

Comment: @ankitpandey I have changed that part. I missed the fact that the first array value is a key that should be added later before the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can break out the initial string into the key segment ("X", "Z") and the values segment ("X6", "A6.5", etc).
Then use regex to get at just the key and value components you want.
Stitch them back together with a list comprehension and a join, and you're good to go.

```
import re

# basic matching patterns
p_k = re.compile("[A-Z]")
p_v = re.compile("'.{1,4}'")

for row in data:
    k, v = row.split("type_list") # split into key/value sections

    k = k.split()[0] 
    new_k = p_k.search(k).group(0)

    new_vs = [x.replace("'","") for x in p_v.findall(v)]
    # rejoin keys and values with the new formatting
    k_v = ",".join(["'%{k}={v};%'".format(k=new_k, v=v) for v in new_vs])
    # add the string wrapping for the new rows
    new_row = "(type_value LIKE ANY ({}))".format(k_v)

    print(new_row)
```

Output:

```
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%X=X6;%','%X=A6.5;%','%X=YZ;%'))
(type_value LIKE ANY ('%Z=30;%'))
```

The regex could be a bit more elegant, and that would save a step or two with cleaning - but this is the idea (and it works as is).

Data:

```
data = ["[(array['X'] <@ type_list AND (array['X6'] <@ value_list OR array['A6.5'] <@ value_list OR array['YZ'] <@ value_list)]",
        "[(array['Z'] <@ type_list AND array['30'] <@ value_list)]"]
```

Comment: there might be multiple `AND` which is not in above example, so `k, v = row.split("AND")` may not work. Can we split like `k, v = row.split("type_list")` because that will be there only once